# org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'narrative' of bean class [com.petstore.model.FreeFormat]:

Tags: spring, weblogic, javabeans, bean-validation

We just got one weird issue for one enterprise application deployed under WebLogic 12c:

> org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'narrative' of bean class [com.petstore.model.FreeFormat]:
>   Bean property 'narrative' is not readable or has an invalid getter
>   method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of
>   the setter?

We have this entity class:

```
public class FreeFormat implements Serializable {
    private String standardText;
    private String openText;

    /** default constructor */
    public FreeFormat() {
    }

    public String getOpenText() {
        return KEString.nullTOBlank(openText);
    }

    public void setOpenText(String openText) {
        this.openText = openText;
    }

    public String getStandardText() {
        return standardText;
    }

    public void setStandardText(String standardText) {
        this.standardText = standardText;
    }

    public String getNarrative(){
        return getStandardText() + "\n" + getOpenText();
    }
```

When new build done and deployed to WebLogic server 12C(Using console, delete old build and install new build, without restarting server), sometimes it had such error:

> > 16:32:43,176 | ERROR | ErrorsTag                | Invalid property 'narrative' of bean class [com.petstore.model.FreeFormat]: Bean
> >     property 'narrative' is not readable or has an invalid getter method:
> >     Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the
> >     setter? | org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag
> >     |   86 | [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '19' for queue:
> >     'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' 
> >     org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid
> >     property 'narrative' of bean class [com.petstore.model.FreeFormat]:
> >     Bean property 'narrative' is not readable or has an invalid getter
> >     method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of
> >     the setter?   at
> >     org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:729)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:721)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:226)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:120)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ErrorsTag.shouldRender(ErrorsTag.java:140)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementBodyTag.writeTagContent(AbstractHtmlElementBodyTag.java:47)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
> >       at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
> >       at
> >     jsp_servlet._transactions._freeformat.__freeformat_edit._jspService(__freeformat_edit.java:2278)  at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:35)    at
> >     weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
> >       at
> >     weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
> >       at
> >     weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)

When server restarted, issue gone, and we run clustered environment and sometime it happened in one instance but worked well in another, it was found in staging server environment, we rebuilt the same environment (Same JDK, WebLogic,etc), but could not reproduce in development environment, we are using Spring Framework 3.1.0.RELEASE version, and just found this issue after migrating quite old version from Java 6 and WebLogic 10 to Java 8 and WebLogic 12C.

Anyone has any suggestions?